# What is the backing property for ngModel directive when you use it without the [()] syntax

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Looking at an angular forms example that I'm editing I see one example that uses the ngModel keyword without assigning it to a backing property name.

```
<input ngModel required type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" >
```

I normally see it with a binding bracket of `[ngModel]="password"` or `[(ngModel)]="password"`

If we use the plain ngModel directive of the first example without an assignment, what backing property is the input data bound to?  Is it not bound to anything and only accesible from `form.values`?  In what use case would you want to use the plain ngModel directive - when you don't need binding and only want to access it from the form values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A use case that comes to my mind is when you don't want to bind it to a field, but you want update your model when it changes, like

```
<input ngModel (ngModelChange)="updateModel($event)"
```

The following code would not work because `ngModelChange` is not a selector matching the `NgModel` directive

```
<input (ngModelChange)="updateModel($event)"
```

therefore you add a bar `ngModel` to get the `NgModel` directive applied and get `ngModelChange` events.

Answer (score 1):

The `ngModel` registers the input field in the `ngForm` directive. The name of the input is used as key.

some-component.html

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="save(form.value)" #form="ngForm" >
  <input type="text" name="title" ngModel />  
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">save</button>
</form>
```

some-component.ts

```
...
save(value: any) {
   console.log(value.title);
}
```

If you remove the `ngModel` from the input field, then `value.title` is gone (undefined).